# Universal app-enable different iOS for iPhone and iPad

Tags: xcode

We would like to enable our app to work on `iPhone` from `iOS8` and up,
and for `iPads`, for `iOS7` and up.

This is to eliminate only the `iPhone4/4s` .

Is there a way to do that in `Xcode` ? you can only chose one restriction.

Comment: No, and the 4S runs ios8 anyway.

Comment: is it "legal" to write that your app is iPhone5 and up?